# dynamically adding form elements in javascript in IE/Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have tried bunch of things but didn't founded a workaround with this

I have this code this works fine on Chrome. But it does't work on mozilla or IE, In the console it doesn't shows up any error. It just doesn't work.

```
<?php

echo"<script>alert('okay');</script>";

?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
    <script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.3">
        function name3() {
            var abc = document.createElement("FORM");
                //abc.setAttribute("method","POST");
            abc.method = "POST";
            abc.action = "http://localhost/2.php";
            var a = document.createElement("INPUT");
                /*a.setAttribute("type","text");
                a.setAttribute("name","a");
                a.setAttribute("value","abc");*/
            a.name = 'a';
            a.value = "abc";
            abc.appendChild(a);
            abc.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "name3();" value = "click">
</html>
```

Instead of a.name, I have also tried using a.setAttribute but still didn't work

Please help!!! Thanks :)

Comment: You don't have a <body> tag. It may cause the problem (Because the DOM is invalid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append form to body and then latter removed it once posted. Currently you are not adding your form to DOM. it actually need to be in the DOM to be sent in a page load.

*Complete Code*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function name3() {
            var form = document.createElement("FORM");
            form.method = "POST";
            form.action = "http://localhost/2.php";
            var a = document.createElement("INPUT");
            a.name = 'a';
            a.value = "abc";
            form.appendChild(a);

            //Apend form to body
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);

            //Submit form
            form.submit();

            // But once the form is sent, it's useless to keep it.
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(form);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="name3();" value="click" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new element to the DOM tree first and then submit the form. If you do not want display them you can add styles to hide the elements.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function name3() {
        var abc = document.createElement("FORM");
            //abc.setAttribute("method","POST");
        abc.method = "POST";
        abc.action = "http://localhost/2.php";
        var a = document.createElement("INPUT");
            /*a.setAttribute("type","text");
            a.setAttribute("name","a");
            a.setAttribute("value","abc");*/
        a.name = 'a';
        a.value = "abc";
        abc.appendChild(a);

        document.getElementById("body").appendChild(abc);
        abc.submit();
    }
</script>
<body id="body">
    <input type = "button" onclick = "name3();" value = "click">
</body>
```